# Pixilating sprite in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, sprite

In each update, my sprite resizes itself based on a variable (OBJECT_X), however when OBJECT_X changes, the sprite becomes more pixilated. I have tried re-loading the image in each update, but this really lags out the game. Any suggestions?

```
import pygame

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 600))
background = pygame.Surface((1000, 600))

OBJECT_SIZE = 500

Tree = pygame.image.load("Resourses/Objects/Tree.png").convert_alpha()

while True:
    Tree = pygame.transform.scale(Tree, (OBJECT_SIZE, OBJECT_SIZE)
    screen.blit(Tree, 500, 300))

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't modify the original pygame.Surface/image if you want to avoid quality losses. The `transform.scale` function returns a new, scaled version of the original image (which doesn't get modified during the scaling), so you can just assign it to a new name:

```
TREE = pygame.image.load("Resourses/Objects/Tree.png").convert_alpha()

while True:
    scaled_tree = pygame.transform.scale(TREE, (OBJECT_SIZE, OBJECT_SIZE)
    screen.blit(scaled_tree, 500, 300))
```

[PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions) recommends to use uppercase letters for constants and lowercase for variables.